# ogr2ogr fileGDB translating points

Tags: gdal, spatialite, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase

I am converting data from spatialite to fileGDB (and reverse) for a project using QGIS and ArcGIS.  When I convert using ogr2ogr (or QGIS) from spatialite to fileGDB, the points are translated slightly during the conversion.  If I convert from spatialite to shapefile, there is no translation.  This is verified by doing a select by location query or by identifying the coordinates.  I have verified this condition in windows, and built gdal/ogr in linux using ESRI's fileGDB library.  Both produce the same results.  Based on my testing, it appears to be the write portion of ESRI's fileGDB library.  I have modified the XYSCALE and XYTOLERANCE settings, but neither appear to change the output.  Can anyone verify, or is there a solution?  The points are only translated slightly, typically 0.0001 ft, but it is enough to make spatial queries fail and prevent point updates.  GDAL version is 1.11.1.